# problems accessing variables in a loop within my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, view

I'm fairly new to Ruby/Rails and I'm having a weird issue that I can't seem to understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

I have the following code in my view

```
<% gameNum = 0 %>
gameNum: <%= gameNum %>
homeTeamIndex: <%= @games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex %>
awayTeamIndex: <%= @games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex %><br />
<%= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex].name %>
<%= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex].name %><br />
<% gameNum = 1 %>
gameNum: <%= gameNum %> 
homeTeamIndex: <%= @games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex %>
awayTeamIndex: <%= @games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex %><br />
<%= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex].name %>
<%= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex].name %><br />

<% (0..@games.count).each do |gameNum| %>
  gameNum: <%= gameNum %>
  homeTeamIndex: <%#= @games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex %>
  awayTeamIndex: <%#= @games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex %> <br />
  <%#= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex].name %>
  <%#= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex].name %>
<% end %>
```

And I get the following results when I view my view:

```
gameNum: 0 homeTeamIndex: 10 awayTeamIndex: 3
Detroit Lions Buffalo Bills
gameNum: 1 homeTeamIndex:  awayTeamIndex: 
Cinncinatti Bengals Cleveland Browns
gameNum: 0 homeTeamIndex:  awayTeamIndex: 
homeTeamIndex: awayTeamIndex:
gameNum: 1 homeTeamIndex:  awayTeamIndex: 
homeTeamIndex: awayTeamIndex:
gameNum: 2 homeTeamIndex:  awayTeamIndex: 
homeTeamIndex: awayTeamIndex:
gameNum: 3 homeTeamIndex:  awayTeamIndex: 
homeTeamIndex: awayTeamIndex:
gameNum: 4 homeTeamIndex:  awayTeamIndex:
```

However, if I uncomment any of the lines:

```
homeTeamIndex: <%#= @games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex %>
awayTeamIndex: <%#= @games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex %> <br />
<%#= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex].name %>
<%#= @NflTeams[@games[gameNum].awayTeamIndex].name %>
```

I get the following error(method name changes based on which line I uncomment):

```
undefined method `homeTeamIndex' for nil:NilClass
```

I really don't understand what is happening within the loop that makes the instance variables unavailable.

I'm hoping someone can tell me what the heck I'm doing wrong because this sure seems like a simple thing to do in a view and I can't get it to work.

**UPDATE**

I changed my view as follows, per Dmitry's advice:

```
<% gameNum = 0 %>
<% (@games).each do |game| %>
  <strong>Game <%= gameNum+1 %>  </strong> <br />
  <%= image_tag(@NflTeams[game.homeTeamIndex].imagePath,
                size: "40") %>
  <%= @NflTeams[game.homeTeamIndex].name %>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VS
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <%= image_tag(@NflTeams[game.awayTeamIndex].imagePath,
                size: "40") %>
  <%= @NflTeams[game.awayTeamIndex].name %> <br />
  <% gameNum += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

And the Models are as follows:

NflTeams

```
class CreateNflTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :nfl_teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :imagePath

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Game

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.integer :homeTeamIndex
      t.integer :awayTeamIndex
      t.integer :spread
      t.integer :week_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The awayTeamIndex and homTeamIndex are an index into the NflTeams model so I can easily pull out the Name and ImagePath.

I am still getting the undefined method on the line:

```
<%= image_tag(@NflTeams[game.homeTeamIndex].imagePath,
              size: "40") %>
```

Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE 2**

I only included the migrations because there isn't much in the models for these two models.
But here it is.

```
class NflTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :week

  validates :homeTeamIndex, :inclusion => { :in => 0..100 }
  validates :awayTeamIndex, :inclusion => { :in => 0..100 }
end
```

And here is the controller code:

```
class WeeksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :confirmed_user

  ...

  def show
    @week = Week.find(params[:id])
    @games = @week.games
    @NflTeams = NflTeam.all
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing you `@games` in a loop correctly. It looks like you are thinking about gameNum in this line:

```
<% (0..@games.count).each do |gameNum| %>
```

as if it is a numerical index and using it to access an object in a collection, in the following line:

```
homeTeamIndex: <%#= @games[gameNum].homeTeamIndex %>
```

This is wrong because "gameNum" is actually your object from a collection of @games fetched for you by magic ruby, so what you need is something like this:

```
<% (@games).each do |game| %>
  gameNum: <%= game.number %>
  homeTeamIndex: <%= game.homeTeamIndex %>
  awayTeamIndex: <%= game.awayTeamIndex %> <br />
  <%= game.homeTeam.name %>
  <%= game.awayTeam.name %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps :)

P.S.
This solution depends on how your models are set up of course, if you can show those it might make your problem clearer for others to explain.

---

### **EDIT - Complete solution**

I will just show you the way to present a peace of info as in your solution.

*To start off a small advise, you mentioned in your comment*

> changed it to just query the database in the form for both the
>   homeTeamIndex and the awayTeamIndex

*While this might work it is a bad practice to place such routines in the view, it is better to define a method to complete such routine in the helper and call it in the view.*

**Now, to the solution...**

First you need to properly define model associations, which are only partially defined judging from the code you have shared. What you need is:

Tell all classes that they are related (which they are) like this:
*I would loose 'Nfl' in team since it makes naming of classes confusing*

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :week
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :home_team_id
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :away_team_id
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, class_name: "Game", foreign_key: :home_team_id
  has_many :away_games, class_name: "Game", foreign_key: :away_team_id
end
```

*Note: Have a look at [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for a more in-depth understanding of those.*

---

**EDIT**

*Corrected model associations above and tested to make sure those are working:)*

Make sure you have the following database schema to back up the associations...

```
  create_table "games", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "game_number"
    t.integer  "week_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "home_team_id"
    t.integer  "away_team_id"
  end

  create_table "teams", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "weeks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**EDIT:** *mind the fact that all tables do include id field by default when you create models in rails*

---

With these associations in place you can now get the week in your controller as you did before:

```
class WeeksController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def show
    @week = Week.find(params[:id])
    @games = @week.games
  end

  ...

end
```

And finally construct your view:
*In WeeksController#show*
*/views/weeks/show.html.erb*

```
<% if @games.any? %>
  <% render @games %>
<% end %>
```

This line "render @games' will search for '/views/games/_game.html.erb' and render it for every game in the collection @games

*/views/games/_game.html.erb - partial view*

```
<strong> Game <%= game.game_number %>  </strong> <br />
<%= image_tag(game.home_team.imagePath, size: "40") %>
<%= game.home_team.name %>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VS
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<%= image_tag(game.away_team.imagePath, size: "40") %>
<%= game.away_team.name %> <br />
```

And that is it, the only fiddly bit is getting the model associations wright which is not too difficult.

Comment: I thought by using the (0..x).each method I was accessing a numerical value, in this case, from 0 to @games.count. In fact, I display the gameNum value and that is what it shows in the example above. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't really need indexes with rails. The rails way of doing things is by using [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Have a look at the [best rails tutorial I have found](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#book_menu) to get a better understanding of how rails work  and also [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) is a great place.

Comment: could you please share your model code (the one that you posted is actually a migration) and a controller.. i will be able to tell you exactly what is going wrong then

Comment: So, I finally changed it to just query the database in the form for both the homeTeamIndex and the awayTeamIndex for each entry and that works.  It seems less efficient than building an array with one database call and using that array in the view but I could not figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct even though I still think there is a problem there.  However, it's probably best handled in a different question.  Thanks!

Comment: I was just writing an edit for my answer to address new info you have given, have a look at that. If you follow it up I am sure you will make it work. I will test my model associations alongside too and post back when I prove that those work :) keep going

Comment: I have tested (check out the edited version of my post) and confirmed that the solution I have described works, have a look at it. hope this will sort you out

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'm going to study up on it to figure out exactly how those relationships are working.  I have one final question, if you have time.  I guess I would still put all of the Team specific info (ie. name, image_path, etc) in the team model.  Is that correct?  You left it out of your example. I really appreciate the help.  I've only been at the ruby/rails development train for two months and there are some things that are just quite different than my previous device driver development.  :-)

Comment: I know how you feel, after mostly working with java and c, rails feel completely different. I left out image from model because I feel that it is redundant. You can have relative image files named by a common naming convention.. say team_[team id]_image.jpg and then have a helper method to construct this path on request pulling relative team.id from the object instance. As per team name and others I just overlooked them concentrating only on the fields that are directly related to your questions. You should be able o build on top of that whatever other functionality you might need...

Comment: By the way, I strongly advise you to follow through [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#book_menu). It is a quite interesting exercise with very good explanations. I felt alot more confident and ready to dig deeper after reading this one.